# urlsave() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I wanted to download the COCO_SAMPLE dataset using fastapi on Google colab:

```
from fastai.data.external import untar_data, URLs
coco_path = untar_data(URLs.COCO_SAMPLE)
```

I am getting the below error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-422a4107f844> in <module>()
      1 from fastai.data.external import untar_data, URLs
----> 2 coco_path = untar_data(URLs.COCO_SAMPLE)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fastdownload/core.py in download_url(url, dest, timeout, show_progress)
     21         pbar.total = tsize
     22         pbar.update(count*bsize)
---> 23     return urlsave(url, dest, reporthook=progress if show_progress else None, timeout=timeout)
     24 
     25 # Cell

TypeError: urlsave() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

Can anyone please help here?